# Mac OS X dynamic linker works sporadically

Tags: c, macos, dyld

I have a program that links to a library "libao_optimization.dylib".  When it runs, most of the time it's fine.  But sporadically, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libao_optimization.dylib
  Referenced from: /User/gw/local/bin/tst_simulated_ngs_image_and_otfs
  Reason: image not found
```

The appropriate paths are in the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I even tried putting the full path in the executable with

```
install_name_tool -change ...
```

But, this error only occurs sometimes.  Other times the library loads fine and the program runs.  Has anyone experienced this on a Mac?

Comment: Is the directory really `/User/gw/…` and not `/Users/gw/…`?  That's unusual on Mac; the `/Users/` directory is the default holder of home directories.  Beware Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan and SIP (System Integrity Protection); you can't so easily go creating folders in arbitrary locations on El Capitan.  Is the `/User` folder network-mounted or anything?  (Also, did Apple really misspell `Libaray` like that?  Copy'n'paste is so much better; it saves us wondering about what you're really seeing!)

Answer (score 0):

[otool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) is the way to debug dyld paths. I normally check with

```
otool -L exeFileName
```

and then adjust the paths with

```
install_name_tool -change
```

For new machines, I configure the env var

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When I still get errors, I test to see if the static version runs fine without errors. For example, for some boost dyld libs, this will work:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

If the errors persist, then I know its not the path problem.